# pyspark dataframe filling group with exact value

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, group-by, apache-spark-sql

I have following pyspark dataframe

```
+-----------+------------------+
|search_term|keyword_match_type|
+-----------+------------------+
|        st1|             EXACT|
|        st1|               DSA|
|        st2|               DSA|
|        st2|               DSA|
|        st2|               DSA|
+-----------+------------------+
```

I want to make a new column in this dataframe which will look like this

```
+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
|search_term|keyword_match_type|exact_match_exist|
+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
|        st1|             EXACT|             True|
|        st1|               DSA|             True|
|        st2|               DSA|            False|
|        st2|               DSA|            False|
|        st2|               DSA|            False|
+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
```

So if at least one `EXACT` exist in group `st1` in col `keyword_match_type`, whole group `st1` in a new column should be filled with `true`.

the below code works fine but it does not do it over groups

```
df.withColumn("exact_match_exist", when(col('keyword_match_type').isin("EXACT"), lit('True')).otherwise(lit('False'))).show()
```

But when I try

```
w = Window().partitionBy("search_term")
df.withColumn("exact_match_exist", when(col('keyword_match_type').over(w).isin("EXACT"), lit('True')).otherwise(lit('False'))).show()
```

I'm getting

> AnalysisException: Expression 'keyword_match_type#25116' not supported
> within a window function.;

Any idea how to overcome this ??

Answer (score 2):

In Spark 3, you can use [`any`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#any) function :

```
from pyspark.sql import Window, functions as F

w = Window.partitionBy("search_term")

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "exact_match_exist",
    F.expr("any(keyword_match_type = 'EXACT')").over(w)
)

df1.show()
# +-----------+------------------+-----------------+
# |search_term|keyword_match_type|exact_match_exist|
# +-----------+------------------+-----------------+
# |        st1|             EXACT|             true|
# |        st1|               DSA|             true|
# |        st2|               DSA|            false|
# |        st2|               DSA|            false|
# |        st2|               DSA|            false|
# +-----------+------------------+-----------------+
```

Or using conditional count like this:

```
df1 = df.withColumn(
    "exact_match_exist",
    F.count(F.when(F.col("keyword_match_type") == "EXACT", 1)).over(w) > 0
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, array and

```
win=Window.partitionBy('search_term')
df.withColumn('exact_match_exist',array_contains(collect_list('keyword_match_type').over(win),'EXACT')).show()

+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
|search_term|keyword_match_type|exact_match_exist|
+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
|        st1|             EXACT|             true|
|        st1|               DSA|             true|
|        st2|               DSA|            false|
|        st2|               DSA|            false|
|        st2|               DSA|            false|
+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
```